# Dataset Creation for Images

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset, image-classification

I am creating an `image dataset` of objects. We have `15 classes` of objects and need to provide a color to the objects also. What colors(aroun 7-10) should we use? I am thinking of using `VIBGYOR`, but not able to find any justification as to why we should be using VIBGYOR and not anything else. Is there any standard practice? Or do people who create such computer vision or image processing datasets have some justification on which colors to use? Some links to research/papers or datasets with justification would be great!

Comment: When you say "provide a color" do you mean that as well as classifying object by type, that you wish to classify it into a colour? Is the colour supposed to be a match to the object's appearance? What domain is this - fashion/clothes? The problem domain is important, as you most likely want your colour categories to match an existing scheme that people already use and understand. You probably do not want a scheme that applies to colours in general.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clear. Yes, we are classifying it based on colour also. its not fashion clothes. We are just considering some basic shapes. The color is not supposed to match to the appearance. We are doing so because we want them to be independent tasks.

Comment: OK. So what does the colour match to, if it does not match the appearance of the shape? What will you use the colour class of a shape for?

Comment: for a given image, we want to independently classify its color and shape. But, we are not sure which colors to choose while making the dataset. Taking any random 7-10 colors doesn't have any justification. we are looking if there is any justification in literature or any intuition or rule of thumb on which colors to use?

Comment: So the colour class does match the appearance of the shape? You said in a previous comment "The color is **not** supposed to match to the appearance. " (emphasis mine). Which is correct? And no, there is no rule of thumb, you are going to create an arbitrary dataset. Unless you are simulating lighting or some other complications in this dataset, the task will be trivial.

Comment: It might help if you explain the purpose of doing this beyond "creating a dataset". It the dataset is to be a toy dataset for trying ML on, this is different to something that tries to replicate a vision task as a human behaves, for basic AI research (where you might want shape and colour classes that match to how humans group things in some specific language).

Comment: @NeilSlater - I think I misunderstood your comment. I meant, the way we are creating the dataset, we want to draw some objects with colors. Like square, triangle and 7 colors. Now, color classification and shape classification are independent tasks. Hope this clarifies. Thanks for your detailed discussion and input about there not being any rule of thumb :)

Comment: No problem. If this is just a toy dataset to practice ML, then definitely there are no rules for you to follow about choosing the colours. If it has some other purpose, such as being compared to human abilities at same task, then there might be some reference material that could help you design the dataset

Comment: @NeilSlater If handy, can you please share the links to reference material. I would like to read them for my understanding. Thanks :)

Comment: Although I do have some understanding of colour perception in machines and humans, I don't have reference material for this task, sorry. I was trying to clarify your goals, to help other experts on the site answer better.